# Export Studio Flow into Json file?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-flow

I was going through the REST v2 Quickstart tutorial where you can create a Flow via the API with a JSON file. Is there a way to export a Flow from a Canvas?

I created a series of wait and reply widgets flow in the Canvas and wanted to share the JSON file to other devs to import it into their local account.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to do that, either via the UI or via the API :)

## User Interface of Twilio Console

1. Open the Flow in [the Twilio Console](https://twilio.com/console/studio).
2. Click on the Trigger Widget and select Show Flow JSON.
   [image]
3. This will display the JSON data that defines your Flow. You can copy this data and store it elsewhere.

[image]

Here's the [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide#importing-and-exporting-flows) page that explains this as well.

## API

You can either use cURL or the [Twilio CLI](https://twil.io/cli) to fetch the definition of a flow:

```bash
export $(cat .env | xargs)
curl https://studio.twilio.com/v2/Flows/$QUIZ_FLOW_SID -u $ACCOUNT_SID:$AUTH_TOKEN -s  | jq ".definition" > studio-flow.json

# or
twilio api:studio:v2:flows:fetch --sid FWXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Here's the [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/v2/flow#fetch-a-flow-resource) page that explains how to do this with the client library in other languages.

PS: You can import via both options as well :)